# can we lazy load packages in angular, can I download required package only when I click on some button?

Tags: npm, angular7, lazy-loading

I am using pdfmake.js(which is around 2mb) and XLSX(which is around 1mb) with angular 7, but they are used only on one page of the application. when I load my home page, in developer tools I can see main.js file size is around 8mb, I implemented lazy loading which reduced main.js file size to 7mb can I somehow further reduce main.js file by loading pdfmake.js and XLSX only when I click on some button?

Answer (score 4):

```
  pdfMake:any;


  async loadPdfMaker() {
    if (!this.pdfMake) {
      const pdfMakeModule = await import('pdfmake/build/pdfmake');
      const pdfFontsModule = await import('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts');
      this.pdfMake = pdfMakeModule.default;
      this.pdfMake.vfs = pdfFontsModule.default.pdfMake.vfs;
    }
  }


  async generatePdf() {

    await this.loadPdfMaker();

    const def = { content: 'A sam`enter code here`ple PDF document generated using Angular and PDFMake' };
    this.pdfMake.createPdf(def).download('optionalName.pdf');;
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You can further reduce the size by importing minified version of the library.

`import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min';`

Comment: Minification is not code's responsibility. It's that of a build tool.